# Discrete mathematics show anisymmetry

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

We let $(A,\leq)$ be an ordered set. We define a relation $\preceq$ on AxA by:
$$(a_1,a_2)\preceq(b_1,b_2) <=>[(a_1\neq b_1) ∧(a_1\leq b_1)]∨ [(a_1=b_1)∧(a_2\leq b_2)]$$
I think we have that $(a_1\neq b_1) ∧(a_1\leq b_1)->a_1<b_1$. So we can reduce it to:
$$(a_1,a_2)\preceq(b_1,b_2) <=>[a_1<b_1]∨ [(a_1=b_1)∧(a_2\leq b_2)]$$
Then I have to show that $\preceq$ is an order-relation. I have shown that we have reflextivity and transitivity. But I got some problem to show that we got antisymmetry.

If I check for the second condition it works while:
$$((a_1=b_1)\wedge(a_2\leq b_2))\wedge((b_1=a_1)\wedge(b_2\leq a_2)) =>(a_1,a_2)=(b_1,b_2)$$
But if I check for the first condition I got:
$$(a_1<b_1)\wedge(b_1<a_1) => emty?$$
Can someone help me proving the antisymmetry?

Comment: MathJax does have `\implies` and  `leftrightarrow` for those signs.

Answer (score 1):

For antisymmetrie, consider the premise

$[(a_1=b_1)\wedge (a_2≤b_2)]\wedge [(b_1=a_1)\wedge (b_2≤a_2)]$.

Since $a_2\leq b_2 \wedge b_2\leq a_2$ is equivalent to $a_2=b_2$, it follows that $(a_1,a_2) = (b_1,b_2)$.

Comment: So I don't have to proove it for the first condition $a_1<b_1$?

Comment: This is only one part of the proof - as requested.

Comment: So I have to split it in 4 cases, as you would do when proving transitivity, or is this enough to prove antisymmetrie?

Comment: Can you answer me on the question above?

Comment: Indeed, there are four cases to consider.

Comment: Yeah, but when I consider:$$(a_1<b_1)\wedge(b_1<a_1) => emty?$$ I got emty and not $a_1=b_1$?. What to do in that case?